# Using graph to depict individual movement pre and post intervention

Tags: data-visualization, likert

I had an intervention with control group and experimental group. Both groups had pre- and post-tests. So I was using 4 graphs to explain in a presentation. (pre-test control, pre-test experiment & post-test control and post-test experiment) Each graph showed responses to a likert scale question with 5 options.

One of the listeners asked me if I could show the shift of 'how many' students had moved from one option in pre-test to some other option in post-test. I can use pivot tables in Excel however, I am not very good in stats.

Can someone kindly guide me through this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with Excel then "Conditional Formatting" ([YouTube Intro](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTztUryXNx0)) is a good candidate.

First, tabulate the pre- and post-scores, and highlight the data:

[image]

Then, under Home > Conditional Formatting, choose the scheme that fits your emphasis:

[image]

The result would be a labelled heat map that shows both numbers and their relative magnitude on a color scale.